# How do I get actual returned value from a chain of promises?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, youtube-api

I'm trying to use a function to get the views count for a video using YouTube API. Although I can see the number of views via console log, I get 'undefined' on the HTML page

I tried .toString() method but to no avail

```
let views = document.createElement('p');
views.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' + getViews(video);

...

const getViews = (video) => {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id=' + video.id + '&key=' + api;
    // console.log(url);
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.items[0].statistics.viewCount); // it works here
        return data.items[0].statistics.viewCount; // but not here 
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
```

I expect the getViews function to return a string containing the views count for a video passed as a function param

Answer (score 0):

`return` the `fetch`:

```
return fetch(url).then(...).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: I get [object Promise] on my page then

Comment: My bad - when you add it to the page, do this: `getViews(video).then(r => r)`. Does that work?

Comment: views.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' + getViews(video).then(r => r);

No, I still get [object Promise] rendered

Comment: the return fetch is important, but how you use it is more important - check this pastebin https://pastebin.com/xAbzpWPL @ВебКирпичи

Comment: `.then(r => r)` is essentially a NOP :p

Comment: your code on pastebin worked lie a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
views.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' + getViews(video);
```

It is impossible for getViews to synchronously return the result of the http call, because the result doesn't exist yet. You'll need to change getViews to return a promise, and then you can get the result of that promise using it's .then method:

```
const getViews = (video) => {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id=' + video.id + '&key=' + api;
    return fetch(url).then((response) => { // <--- added return
        return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
        return data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
};

getViews(video)
  .then(viewCount => {
    // Moved the code into the .then
    let views = document.createElement('p');
    views.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' + viewCount;
  });
```